# &#x9CE0;, &#xEE839; and others

Tags: unicode, utf-8, decode

How to decode those?

Comment: What language and character set/encoding do you use?

Comment: @Gumbo: *Please* tell me you’re not considering that those code points are **not Unicode** ⁉  Do people actually **do** that⁇ Please say it’s not so‼  (PS: Like my code points? :)

Comment: @Oded: I actually believe it is not the same question.

Comment: @tchrist: *I* know that these character references represent characters in the Unicode character set.

Comment: @Oded: Sure, in the other question, some numbskull double-escaped the UTF-8 as though it were some 8-bit encoding, probably ISO 8859-1. In this question, that hasn’t happened, as the code points are well above the 8-bit mark.

Answer (score 0):

These are XML <strike>entities</strike> character references.

You can decode them along with the rest of your XML with an XML parser.

Comment: They are not entities, they are just character references. *amp* is an entity. And `&amp;` is a entity reference referencing the entity named *amp*.

Comment: These character references were introduced with SGML. In fact, XML is just a subset of SGML.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say “decode”?  They represent the Unicode characters represented by those two hex numbers. That’s pretty simple, so you must be asking for something else.

Are you asking what sorts of things are known about those code points?  This might help:

```
$ uniprops 9ce0 ee839
U+9CE0 ‹鳠› \N{ U+9CE0 }:
    \w \pL \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned
       InCJKUnifiedIdeographs L Lo Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph
       GrBase Han Hani ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Ideo
       Ideographic Letter L_ Other_Letter Print UIdeo
       Unified_Ideograph Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS
U+EE839 ‹U+EE839› \N{ U+EE839 }:
    \pC \p{Cn}
    All Any InNoBlock C Other Cn Unassigned Zzzz Unknown
```

So the second code point is currently unassigned, but the first one is up in the CJK Unified Ideographs block.

Was there something else you were curious about?

Comment: I don’t understand what sort of conversion you care to effect.  No conversion is necessary.  And I guarantee you that **ALL** characters in the file are Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

As others note, you've probably got some Unicode character references there. Assuming the other characters in your input are already valid UTF-8, you could convert the references to UTF-8 with something like this (I'm assuming PHP as you asked about it in related question)

```
//take 1-4 byte hex string, convert to UTF-8 byte sequence
function hex2utf8($hex)
{
    //pad to 8 hex digits (32 bits)
    $hex=str_pad($hex, 8, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

    //build binary data octet by octet
    $decode='';
    while (!empty($hex))
    {
        $byte=substr($hex,0,2);
        $hex=substr($hex,2);
        $decode.=chr(hexdec($byte));
    }

    //binary data is UTF-32, convert it to UTF-8
    return iconv('UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8', $decode);;
}

function convertReferencesToUTF8($str)
{
    return preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'hex2utf8("\\1")', $str);
}


$encoded="Unicode references &#x9CE0;, &#xEE839;";
$utf8=convertReferencesToUTF8($encoded);
```

This seems a lot of code, maybe someone else will suggest something simpler.